# Hibernate: rollback in unittest produces when finishing "Transaction not successfully started"

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, rollback

when i do a rollback within a unit test the following exception is thrown after the test.

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:679)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:518)
at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:185)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:406)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:91)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:179)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:676)
... 25 more
```

I have the impression that the transaction is closed after the rollback and a new one is created. This new one is not started, though, which then produces the error when the tests tries to close it.

the test:

```
    package de.company.backend.web;

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import de.company.backend.hibernate.HibernateUtil;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @Transactional
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/app-context.xml", "/test-app-context.xml" })
    public class RollbackTest {

        @Test
        public void testRollback() {
            HibernateUtil.rollback();
        }

    }
```

form the appcontext

```
<!-- make @Transactional working -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Use open session in view pattern for json/rest controller + transaction is similarly opened/closed -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />            
        <property name="flushModeName">  
            <value>FLUSH_AUTO</value>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

hibernateUtil

```
    package de.company.backend.hibernate;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;

    import de.company.backend.spring.SpringFactory;

    public class HibernateUtil {

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return (SessionFactory) SpringFactory
                    .generate("sessionFactory");
        }

        public static Session getCurrentSession() {
            return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        }

        public static Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
            Transaction transaction = getCurrentSession().getTransaction();
            return transaction;
        }

        public static void flush() {
            getCurrentSession().flush();
        }

        public static void commit() {
            getCurrentTransaction().commit();
        }

        public static void rollback() {
            Transaction transaction = getCurrentTransaction();
            transaction.rollback();
        }

    }
```

Does anybody have some advice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to test here but the scenario is flawed. It is wrong to call direct rollback on transaction you haven't started.

Comment: this is just the the part of my test which creates the error. The real scenario is if an exception occurs a status is set accordingly and the transaction is rolled back. This rollback works, so the direct rollback i call works just fine. The rollback which is called by the unit test though throws the described exception. Is it understandable what i am trying to do? If not please ask again

Comment: Further infos: after the rollback the current transaction is not the same as before the call

Comment: You are trying to roll back transaction started by the test framework here. The test framework is rolling back at the end itself and fails because of your manual rollback. Unfortunately the posted code is too simplified and I can hardly figure out what real scenario looks like.

Comment: @mrembisz thank you for you effort. Actually this is the entire test which fails, so there is no simplification. how does it come though i wrote this test? This part of my code creates the error, so i removed everything else from it. What was the case in the first place? A web service does modify some entities, if an error occurs, it should roll back the transaction and return a custom error msg. This behavior works in the real scenario but i would like to have it covered by a test. However, whenever i use a rollback in the test environment the described error occurs.

Comment: With what kind of information can I help to explain the issue more accurate? I highly appreciate your help. I'm badly stuck here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you are calling rollback in your production code in exception handler? In spring you should rather let the framework rollback itself. If method annotated with `@Transactional` throws an exception, spring will detect that and rollback. You should catch exception outside the method - upon catch transaction will already be closed and rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i let spring handle the exception and made spring to produce the corresponding json based on this explanation: 
[Spring 3 exception handling using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641091/spring-3-exception-handling-using-json)